# When a player joins my csgo server, map is stuck on 0%

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive

When someone joins my server they are stuck at loading 0%.
I put maps on my server (maps folder).
Can someone help me whit this problem?

Comment: Custom maps or default?

Comment: Custom (aim_redline)

Comment: Does the server's user account have read access to the file/folder? And the players need to allow downloads (cl_downloadfilter).

Comment: Does this happen to everybody or only one player? If its everyone maybe the map is really on the server, but won't allow to be downloaded because of user permissions. It could also be their firewall blocking the download.